# Detect moving the windows from one display to another

Tags: macos, cocoa, opengl

I have a window with an opengl view where content ist rendered. The problem I have in macOS is, that when I move the window from one monitor to the other, its content gets messed up. A redraw fixes the issue. Thus I need to redraw the GL Area when it gets moved from one monitor to the other. Is there any way to detect the transition of the window from one monitor to the other?

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about macOS, but I'm sure you can query which pixel coordinates belong to which physical monitor (for example by using [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/quartz_display_services)). If you hook into the move event of the window, just test whether your window crosses the screen boundaries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can register for notifications that fire when the view's window changes screens: [NSWindowDidChangeScreenNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdidchangescreennotification)

Comment: I suggest to also handle the [NSWindowDidExposeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindowdidexposenotification?language=objc) in the same way.